# How to avoid big switches when changing C# lineShapes

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on a simple drum machine and am trying to implement a playback position bar by showing and hiding line objects. The bar will have 32 positions in total. I currently have a large switch statement.

```
switch (pos)
{
    case 1:
        lineShape1.Visible = true;
        lineShape32.Visible = false;
        break;
    case 2:
        lineShape2.Visible = true;
        lineShape1.Visible = false;
        break;
    case 3:
        lineShape3.Visible = true;
        lineShape2.Visible = false;
        break;
    //cases repeated 32 times
}
```

I would like to implement something like this,

```
CheckBox snabox = this.Controls["checkBox" + pos.ToString()] as CheckBox;
if (snabox.Checked)
{
    Snare_Click(null, null);
}
```

where the name is automatically changed to test a specific check box.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not add them to a `List<>` or array and use the indexer to set the objects visibility?

Something like

```
lineShapes[pos-1].Visible = true;
pos == 1 ? lineShapes[lineShapes.Length - 1].Visible = false : lineShapes[pos-2].Visible = false;
```